# SQL Query CREATE TABLE on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, database, conditional-statements

I am trying to deduplicate a large table where values are present but broken into several rows.

For example:

Table 1: Client_Code,Account#, First and last names, address.

Table 2: Client_Code,Account#, First and last names, address, TAX_ID.

Now what I want to do may seem pretty obvious at this point.

I want my results to pull from Table 1 into a new table and the query to be "Select From Table 1 where client code and account# from table 1 match client code and account# from table 2."  TAble 2 has all values populated, Table 1 has everyone except TAX ID.

The code i tried looked like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Dedupe_1 AS SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1`
WHERE `TABLE 1`.`Client_Code`=`TABLE 2`.`Client_Code`
AND
WHERE `TABLE 1`.`account#`=`TABLE 2`.`account#`
ORDER BY `TABLE 2`.`account#`
```

I keep getting a syntax error.  I am very new to this programming language so I apologize if this question is hard to understand.

I was just under the impression that I could call to a field from another table by simply using the 'WHERE' statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use an `exists` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE Dedupe_1 AS
    SELECT *
    FROM `TABLE 1` t1
    WHERE EXISTS (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.Client_Code = t1.Client_Code and t2.`account#` = t1.`account#`
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Join to connect two tables. You can make use of common column among two tables for Join statement. Common syntax goes like

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column 2 and as many you want in common table
FROM table1 name
INNER JOIN table2 name
ON table1.commoncolumn=table2.Common column;
```

You may learn more about joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).